# How to remove folder from showing when running the svn status command?

Tags: svn

I have pulled in an `assets` folder which has images etc in it. Now whenever I run `svn status`it shows all of the files in a list. How do I get it to not show this folder in the status and just show the files that have been changed etc.

I understand you can do the following, but its not really solving the problem: `svn status | grep -v '^\?'`

When I am using git I run `git checkout assets` and they disappear off the `git status` list.

**Example of how it shows when you run** `svn status` :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [SVN red book says](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html):

> With --quiet (-q), it prints only summary information about locally
>   modified items.

So you can use following command:

```
svn status --quiet
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
svn propedit svn:ignore.
```

You'll get a file. In that, enter your images folder.